# Does Java have a bounded Collection with removal strategy?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java)

Does java include a native class which allows a **maximum number** of elements and if I input one element more, it **automatically removes** an old one (e.g. based on **natural sorting**)?

If not, I can write it myself of course, but I just wanted to ask.

Comment: Your answer in this edited question: [ffriend's Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878026/is-there-a-priorityqueue-implementation-with-fixed-capacity-and-custom-comparato)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots.

You can use a Queue, and specify a fixed length. Implement your own using an ArrayList that removes element 0 every time a new element is added that increases the size past your limit.

A popular technique is to make a `queue` with a LinkedHashMap

```
  queue = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>()
  {
     @Override
     protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<Integer, String> eldest)
     {
        return this.size() > yourMaxSize;   
     }
  };
```