# Fastest way to sort arraylist of objects by value of a property

Tags: vb.net

Just as an example, I have a bananaTreeArray which is filled with 1000 BananaTree objects. Each of those BananaTree objects has a public property called Bananas. What is the fastest/easiest way for me to find the 5 BananaTree's with the most banana's?

Comment: You don't need to sort if you want to find the greatest number.

Comment: In what other way could I do this?

Comment: there are some example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395648/largest-5-in-array-of-10-numbers-without-sorting) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList` but a generic and strongly typed `List(Of T)`, in this case a `List(Of BananaTree)`. Then it's simple with LINQ:

```
Dim top5Bananas = From btree In bananaTreeArray
                  Order by btree.Bananas Descending
                  Take 5
```

If it's really an `ArrayList` you have to cast every object:

```
Dim top5Bananas = From btree In bananaTreeArray.Cast(of BananaTree)()
                  Order by btree.Bananas Descending
                  Take 5
```

You can either loop this query with a `For Each` or create a list/array, f.e.:

```
Dim top5BananaList = top5Bananas.ToList()
```

Comment: based on this, you can use `Dim top5Bananas = btree.OrderByDescending(function(b) b.Bananas).Take(5)`

Comment: @KeithMifsud: yes, that's method syntax, doesn't make a real difference. I often prefer query syntax in VB.NET because it's more powerful (than in C#, f.e. `Take` is supported) and more readable (because of the ugly `Function`-keyword).

Comment: yes, they are both doing the same thing, I just posted it to let the OP have both choices presented to him. Personally, with complex queries, method syntax helps me more :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved my problem! If I understand you correctly, I should always use List instead of Arraylist?

Comment: Yes. There's no reason to use ArrayList anymore