# top 5 integers in shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to get the top 5 integers in a shared preference file. All I have is I put 35 numbers with keys in a shared preference file and I want the top 5. I need to get them in another activity, and that is why I used shared preferences. The top 5 numbers could change, and I want the data to be saved permanently. The way the numbers change is by checkboxes, and if the user hits a checkbox the number for that key increases. If there is a better way to write the code or you have a solution, could you please write it down below?

```
private CheckBox yCheckbox;
private CheckBox nCheckbox;
private Button button;
public static int checker = 0;
public static final String CravingDatabse = "Cravings";
private int b;
private int toastChecker = 0;
CheckBox phone, alcohol, tv, driving, food, coffee, workBreak, sex, bed, bar, party, concert, someoneElseSmoke,
        friendsWhoSmoke, tasteCigarette, cigaretteSmoke, handlingCigarettes, handsAndMouth, withdrawal, stressed,
        anxious, excited, bored, sad, happy, lonely, satisfied, relaxed, location, fightingWithFriends, morningRoutine,
        bills, boss, arguing, bigEvent;

int phoneN, alcoholN, tvN, drivingN, foodN, coffeeN, workBreakN, sexN, bedN, barN, partyN, concertN, someoneElseSmokeN,
        friendsWhoSmokeN, tasteCigaretteN, cigaretteSmokeN, handlingCigarettesN, handsAndMouthN, withdrawalN, stressedN,
        anxiousN, excitedN, boredN, sadN, happyN, lonelyN, satisfiedN, relaxedN, locationN, fightingWithFriendsN, morningRoutineN,
        billsN, bossN, arguingN, bigEventN;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.smoking_craving);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("huan", MODE_PRIVATE);
    b = prefs.getInt("amount", 0);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(CravingDatabse, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cravingCheck);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (checker == 1) {
                //MainActivity.b = b + 1;
                //checker = 0;
                b = b + 1;
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("huan", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs.edit();
                editor1.putInt("amount", b);
                editor1.apply();
            }
            if (toastChecker == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Way to go!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                toastChecker = 0;
                int urgesPassed = sharedPreferences.getInt("urgesPassed", 0);
                editor.putInt("urgesPassed", ++urgesPassed);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (alcoholN == 1) {
                int alcoholS = sharedPreferences.getInt("alcoholS", 0);
                editor.putInt("alcoholS", ++alcoholS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (phoneN == 1) {
                int phoneS = sharedPreferences.getInt("phoneS", 0);
                editor.putInt("phoneS", ++phoneS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (tvN == 1) {
                int tvS = sharedPreferences.getInt("tvS", 0);
                editor.putInt("tvS", ++tvS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (drivingN == 1) {
                int drivingS = sharedPreferences.getInt("drivingS", 0);
                editor.putInt("drivingS", ++drivingS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (foodN == 1) {
                int foodS = sharedPreferences.getInt("foodS", 0);
                editor.putInt("foodS", ++foodS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (coffeeN == 1) {
                int coffeeS = sharedPreferences.getInt("coffeeS", 0);
                editor.putInt("coffeeS", ++coffeeS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (workBreakN == 1) {
                int workBreakS = sharedPreferences.getInt("workBreakS", 0);
                editor.putInt("workBreakS", ++workBreakS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (sexN == 1) {
                int sexS = sharedPreferences.getInt("sexS", 0);
                editor.putInt("sexS", ++sexS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (bedN == 1) {
                int bedS = sharedPreferences.getInt("bedS", 0);
                editor.putInt("bedS", ++bedS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (barN == 1) {
                int barS = sharedPreferences.getInt("barS", 0);
                editor.putInt("barS", ++barS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (partyN == 1) {
                int partyS = sharedPreferences.getInt("partyS", 0);
                editor.putInt("partyS", ++partyS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (concertN == 1) {
                int concertS = sharedPreferences.getInt("concertS", 0);
                editor.putInt("concertS", ++concertS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (someoneElseSmokeN == 1) {
                int someoneElseSmokeS = sharedPreferences.getInt("someoneElseSmokeS", 0);
                editor.putInt("someoneElseSmokeS", ++someoneElseSmokeS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (friendsWhoSmokeN == 1) {
                int friendsWhoSmokeS = sharedPreferences.getInt("friendsWhoSmokeS", 0);
                editor.putInt("friendsWhoSmokeS", ++friendsWhoSmokeS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (tasteCigaretteN == 1) {
                int tasteCigaretteS = sharedPreferences.getInt("tasteCigaretteS", 0);
                editor.putInt("tasteCigaretteS", ++tasteCigaretteS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (cigaretteSmokeN == 1) {
                int cigaretteSmokeS = sharedPreferences.getInt("cigaretteSmokeS", 0);
                editor.putInt("cigaretteSmokeS", ++cigaretteSmokeS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (handlingCigarettesN == 1) {
                int handlingCigarettesS = sharedPreferences.getInt("handlingCigarettesS", 0);
                editor.putInt("handlingCigarettesS", ++handlingCigarettesS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (handsAndMouthN == 1) {
                int handsAndMouthS = sharedPreferences.getInt("handsAndMouthS", 0);
                editor.putInt("handsAndMouthS", ++handsAndMouthS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (withdrawalN == 1) {
                int withdrawalS = sharedPreferences.getInt("withdrawalS", 0);
                editor.putInt("withdrawalS", ++withdrawalS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (stressedN == 1) {
                int stressedS = sharedPreferences.getInt("stressedS", 0);
                editor.putInt("stressedS", ++stressedS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (anxiousN == 1) {
                int anxiousS = sharedPreferences.getInt("anxiousS", 0);
                editor.putInt("anxiousS", ++anxiousS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (excitedN == 1) {
                int excitedS = sharedPreferences.getInt("excitedS", 0);
                editor.putInt("excitedS", ++excitedS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (boredN == 1) {
                int boredS = sharedPreferences.getInt("boredS", 0);
                editor.putInt("boredS", ++boredS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (sadN == 1) {
                int sadS = sharedPreferences.getInt("sadS", 0);
                editor.putInt("sadS", ++sadS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (happyN == 1) {
                int happyS = sharedPreferences.getInt("happyS", 0);
                editor.putInt("happyS", ++happyS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (lonelyN == 1) {
                int lonelyS = sharedPreferences.getInt("lonelyS", 0);
                editor.putInt("lonelyS", ++lonelyS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (satisfiedN == 1) {
                int satisfiedS = sharedPreferences.getInt("satisfiedS", 0);
                editor.putInt("satisfiedS", ++satisfiedS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (relaxedN == 1) {
                int relaxedS = sharedPreferences.getInt("relaxedS", 0);
                editor.putInt("relaxedS", ++relaxedS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (locationN == 1) {
                int locationS = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationS", 0);
                editor.putInt("locationS", ++locationS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (fightingWithFriendsN == 1) {
                int fightingWithFriendsS = sharedPreferences.getInt("fightingWithFriendsS", 0);
                editor.putInt("fightingWithFriendsS", ++fightingWithFriendsS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (morningRoutineN == 1) {
                int morningRoutineS = sharedPreferences.getInt("morningRoutineS", 0);
                editor.putInt("morningRoutineS", ++morningRoutineS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (billsN == 1) {
                int billsS = sharedPreferences.getInt("billsS", 0);
                editor.putInt("billsS", ++billsS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (bossN == 1) {
                int bossS = sharedPreferences.getInt("bossS", 0);
                editor.putInt("bossS", ++bossS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (arguingN == 1) {
                int arguingS = sharedPreferences.getInt("arguingS", 0);
                editor.putInt("arguingS", ++arguingS);
                editor.apply();
            }
            if (bigEventN == 1) {
                int bigEventS = sharedPreferences.getInt("bigEventS", 0);
                editor.putInt("bigEventS", ++bigEventS);
                editor.apply();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(SmokingAndCravingCheck.this, MainActivity.class);
            SmokingAndCravingCheck.this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    yCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yesCheckBox);
    nCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.noCheckBox);

    yCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (yCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                nCheckbox.setChecked(false);
                checker = 1;
                toastChecker = 0;
            } else if (!yCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                checker = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    nCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (nCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                yCheckbox.setChecked(false);
                toastChecker = 1;
                checker = 0;
            } else if (!nCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                toastChecker = 0;
            }
        }
    });


    phone = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.onPhoneCheckBtn);
    phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (phone.isChecked()) {
                phoneN = 1;
            } else if (!phone.isChecked()) {
                phoneN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    alcohol = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alcoholCheckBtn);
    alcohol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (alcohol.isChecked()) {
                alcoholN = 1;
            } else if (!alcohol.isChecked()) {
                alcoholN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    tv = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tvCheckBtn);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tv.isChecked()) {
                tvN = 1;
            } else if (!tv.isChecked()) {
                tvN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    driving = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.drivingCheckBtn);
    driving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (driving.isChecked()) {
                drivingN = 1;
            } else if (!driving.isChecked()) {
                drivingN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    food = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mealCheckBtn);
    food.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (food.isChecked()) {
                foodN = 1;
            } else if (!food.isChecked()) {
                foodN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    coffee = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cofeeCheckBtn);
    coffee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (coffee.isChecked()) {
                coffeeN = 1;
            } else if (!coffee.isChecked()) {
                coffeeN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    workBreak = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.workCheckBtn);
    workBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (workBreak.isChecked()) {
                workBreakN = 1;
            } else if (!workBreak.isChecked()) {
                workBreakN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    sex = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sexCheckBtn);
    sex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (sex.isChecked()) {
                sexN = 1;
            } else if (!sex.isChecked()) {
                sexN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    bed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bedCheckBtn);
    bed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bed.isChecked()) {
                bedN = 1;
            } else if (!bed.isChecked()) {
                bedN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    bar = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.barCheckBtn);
    bar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bar.isChecked()) {
                barN = 1;
            } else if (!bar.isChecked()) {
                barN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    party = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.partyCheckBtn);
    party.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (party.isChecked()) {
                partyN = 1;
            } else if (!party.isChecked()) {
                partyN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    concert = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.concertCheckBtn);
    concert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (concert.isChecked()) {
                concertN = 1;
            } else if (!concert.isChecked()) {
                concertN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    someoneElseSmoke = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.someoneElseSmokeCheckBtn);
    someoneElseSmoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (someoneElseSmoke.isChecked()) {
                someoneElseSmokeN = 1;
            } else if (!someoneElseSmoke.isChecked()) {
                someoneElseSmokeN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    friendsWhoSmoke = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendsCheckBtn);
    friendsWhoSmoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (friendsWhoSmoke.isChecked()) {
                friendsWhoSmokeN = 1;
            } else if (!friendsWhoSmoke.isChecked()) {
                friendsWhoSmokeN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    tasteCigarette = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tasteCigaretteCheckBtn);
    tasteCigarette.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tasteCigarette.isChecked()) {
                tasteCigaretteN = 1;
            } else if (!tasteCigarette.isChecked()) {
                tasteCigaretteN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    cigaretteSmoke = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.smokeCheckBtn);
    cigaretteSmoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (cigaretteSmoke.isChecked()) {
                cigaretteSmokeN = 1;
            } else if (!cigaretteSmoke.isChecked()) {
                cigaretteSmokeN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    handlingCigarettes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.handlingCheckBtn);
    handlingCigarettes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (handlingCigarettes.isChecked()) {
                handlingCigarettesN = 1;
            } else if (!handlingCigarettes.isChecked()) {
                handlingCigarettesN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    handsAndMouth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.handsCheckBtn);
    handsAndMouth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (handsAndMouth.isChecked()) {
                handsAndMouthN = 1;
            } else if (!handsAndMouth.isChecked()) {
                handsAndMouthN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    withdrawal = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.withdrawalCheckBtn);
    withdrawal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (withdrawal.isChecked()) {
                withdrawalN = 1;
            } else if (!withdrawal.isChecked()) {
                withdrawalN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    stressed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.stressedCheckBtn);
    stressed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (stressed.isChecked()) {
                stressedN = 1;
            } else if (!stressed.isChecked()) {
                stressedN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    anxious = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.anxiousCheckBtn);
    anxious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (anxious.isChecked()) {
                anxiousN = 1;
            } else if (!anxious.isChecked()) {
                anxiousN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    excited = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.excitedCheckBtn);
    excited.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (excited.isChecked()) {
                excitedN = 1;
            } else if (!excited.isChecked()) {
                excitedN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    bored = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.boredCheckBtn);
    bored.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bored.isChecked()) {
                boredN = 1;
            } else if (!bored.isChecked()) {
                boredN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    sad = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sadCheckBtn);
    sad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (sad.isChecked()) {
                sadN = 1;
            } else if (!sad.isChecked()) {
                sadN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    happy = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.happyCheckBtn);
    happy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (happy.isChecked()) {
                happyN = 1;
            } else if (!happy.isChecked()) {
                happyN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    lonely = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lonelyCheckBtn);
    lonely.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (lonely.isChecked()) {
                lonelyN = 1;
            } else if (!lonely.isChecked()) {
                lonelyN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    satisfied = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.satisfiedCheckBtn);
    satisfied.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (satisfied.isChecked()) {
                satisfiedN = 1;
            } else if (!satisfied.isChecked()) {
                satisfiedN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    relaxed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.relaxedCheckBtn);
    relaxed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (relaxed.isChecked()) {
                relaxedN = 1;
            } else if (!relaxed.isChecked()) {
                relaxedN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    location = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.locationCheckBtn);
    location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (location.isChecked()) {
                locationN = 1;
            } else if (!location.isChecked()) {
                locationN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    fightingWithFriends = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fightingWithFriendsCheckBtn);
    fightingWithFriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fightingWithFriends.isChecked()) {
                fightingWithFriendsN = 1;
            } else if (!fightingWithFriends.isChecked()) {
                fightingWithFriendsN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    morningRoutine = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.morningRoutineCheckBtn);
    morningRoutine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (morningRoutine.isChecked()) {
                morningRoutineN = 1;
            } else if (!morningRoutine.isChecked()) {
                morningRoutineN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    bills = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.payingBillsCheckBtn);
    bills.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bills.isChecked()) {
                billsN = 1;
            } else if (!bills.isChecked()) {
                billsN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    boss = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bossCheckBtn);
    boss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (boss.isChecked()) {
                bossN = 1;
            } else if (!boss.isChecked()) {
                bossN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    arguing = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.arguingCheckBtn);
    arguing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (arguing.isChecked()) {
                arguingN = 1;
            } else if (!arguing.isChecked()) {
                arguingN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    bigEvent = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bigEventCheckBtn);
    bigEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bigEvent.isChecked()) {
                bigEventN = 1;
            } else if (!bigEvent.isChecked()) {
                bigEventN = 0;
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: `I need to get them in another activity, and that is why I used shared preferences.` Sort the values and store the top 5 in an array you'll pass to the next Activity by using a Bundle. That's how to pass values to another Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data in another activity, I would recommend using the Intent system. [Here's a link to help you on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

The intent system is much faster than reading and writing to a file on the users device. Also you can pass whole objects to it, and is much easier than using the Shared Preferences method you've used above.

After you have all the integers from an intent/however, you would pull all the integers out into an array and return an int array of 5 numbers with a helper method, finding the top 5 numbers with something like what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395648/largest-5-in-array-of-10-numbers-without-sorting), then whenever you need to get the top 5 numbers in an array, call the helper method on whichever array you'd like.