# Big(O) of finding K element in a MinHeap build from 2 unsorted arrays

Tags: scala, big-o, priority-queue

Given the question here. https://www.careercup.com/question?id=9406769 which asks:
Given two unsorted int arrays, find the kth element in the merged, sorted array. 
k element in an index that starts at 1.

What would be the BigO performance of the solution below (prints 1):

```
    object MergeTwoArraysFindK {

  import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

  def findK(arrayOne: Array[Int], arrayTwo: Array[Int], k: Int): Int = {
    implicit val ord = Ordering[Int].reverse
    val minHeap = new PriorityQueue[Int] ++= (arrayOne ++ arrayTwo).iterator
    for (i <- 1 to k)
      if (i == k)
        return minHeap.dequeue()
      else
        minHeap.dequeue()
    -1
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val arrayOne = Array[Int](3, 4, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4)
    val arrayTwo = Array[Int](5, 4, 1, 0, 9, 8)
    println(findK(arrayOne, arrayTwo, 4))
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know the big-O of your operations? (add to queue, dequue, etc)?

Comment: BTW, you might want a bounded priority queue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878026/is-there-a-priorityqueue-implementation-with-fixed-capacity-and-custom-comparato

Comment: I think the answer should be O(n) for the time searching the heap. Now the complete time I believe it should include building the heap by merging the two arrays into the heap which it is probably n + O(log n). Where n should be the concatenation of the arrays and O(log n) is the insertion. Am I right?

Comment: O(n) + O(log n) is just O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes O(n) time to build the heap, and it requires O(n) extra space.

Finding the kth item is O(k log n) Each call to `minheap.dequeue` requires O(log n), and you're making `k` calls.

This approach works if you have enough memory to hold everything in memory. If you don't have enough memory, say you're doing this with two absolutely huge files, then the process is slightly different. See [Time complexity of Kth smallest using Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42179835/56778).

Comment: Just the clear answer that I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: So according to your answer O(k log n) == K * O(n) ?

Comment: @Fabio: Thank you for pointing out my error. See the correction. Each call to `minheap.dequeue` requires O(log n).