# Can method add of class PriorityQueue<E> return false?

Tags: java, priority-queue

In PriorityQueue class description in oracle, specifically about method *add*, the page says about add's return value:

Returns:
    true (as specified by Collection.add(E))

Does it mean that this method always returns true?

Thanks in advance !

Link to class description: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: it can return true. It can also throw an Exception, in which case, it won't return anything

Comment: It's funny that the title says, "Can it return false?" and inside your description you ask, "Does it always return true?" So if somebody were to answer "Yes," then he'd be right ... or wrong ... depending on which question he answered. You should take care in the future to be consistent with how you ask your questions.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, thank you for your comment. Will take notice of it

Answer (score 2):

If you clicked on the link in the documentation you would read what [`Collection.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) says about the return value:

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional
>   operation). Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the
>   call. (**Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and
>   already contains the specified element.**)

So the contract for the return value is that it must always return true **except** if:

1. The collection does not allow duplicates
2. The element is already present

Does the `PriorityQueue` permit duplicates? Yes. Hence it can never return `false`.

Comment: you forgot the except "when an exception is thrown"

Comment: @Stultuske Are you saying that when an exception is thrown the method returns `false`?

Comment: no, when an exeption is thrown it returns neither true nor false. It throws an exception

Comment: what @TimCastelijns said. You stated that it must always return true except in case it doesn't allow duplicates and it would be a duplicate. Which is incomplete. It doesn't return true in case of an exception being thrown, which was my point.

Comment: @Stultuske The value returned is always relevant if the function returns at all, so I believe the statement is self-explaining as the documentation is.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta yes, but according to your explanation, there is always a value returned. again, I don't disagree with the explanation of true/false, I 'm merely stating it's incomplete

Comment: Giacomo Alzetta, thank you for the fast reply and coherent answer!

Answer (score 2):

The method `add` is defined as

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return offer(e);
}
```

The method `offer` is defined as

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    modCount++;
    int i = size;
    if (i >= queue.length)
        grow(i + 1);
    size = i + 1;
    if (i == 0)
        queue[0] = e;
    else
        siftUp(i, e);
    return true;
}
```

So the answer to your question is yes. This current implementation always returns `true` unless an exception is thrown.

The contract of `Collection#add` says the method returns "`true` if this collection changed as a result of the call". Since `PriorityQueue` isn't a final class and it may have children, we can't say "it will never return `false`". I may implement a [bounded `PriorityQueue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878026/is-there-a-priorityqueue-implementation-with-fixed-capacity-and-custom-comparato). I may come up with a `PriorityQueue` that rejects particular values or doesn't accept new values at all.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Integer integer) {
    super.add(integer);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the detailed and thorough answer!