# Getting oldest n elements of a Java list with conditional logic applied

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Java 8. I have a list of widgets (`List<Widget>`) where a widget looks like:

```
public class Widget {

  // lots of fields
  private Date createTime;

  // getters, setters & ctors
  
}
```

All `createTime` values will be in the past; none in the future. And the present doesn't really exist. ;-)

I don't have any control over how the list of widgets gets created, or how many get created. But the list of widgets might be huge and so I need to use this list of widgets to figure out which ones I want to delete (`deleteList`). However, I need to apply some Stream API filters/magic to this list so that I wind up either with:

1. if the number of widgets (`numWidgets`) is less than or equal to the number I want to retain (`retentionSize`), then I want to keep all the widgets and so I want my `deleteList` to be empty
2. else, `numWidgets > retentionSize`, and so I want my `deleteList` to only contain the **oldest** `numWidgets - retentionSize` (I'll provide an example below)

Again the algorithm here is:

```
if numWidgets > retentionSize
  i want oldest (numWidgets - retentionSize)

if numWidgets <= retentionSize
  i want an empty list
```

Examples:

1. `numWidgets` is 83 and `retentionSize` is 90; since `numWidgets <= retentionSize` then `deleteList` is empty
2. `numWidgets` is 107 and `retentionSize` is 90; since `numWidgets > retentionSize` then `deleteList` is the **oldest** `numWidgets - retentionSize` (107 - 90 = 17) widgets in the list

My best attempt thus far using the Stream API is:

```
// again I don't control how I get allWidgets
List<Widget> allWidgets = getSomehow();
int numWidgets = allWidgets.size();
List<Widget> oldest = (numWidgets > retentionSize)
  ? allWidgets.sort(Comparator.comparing(widget -> widget.getCreateTime()))
  : Collections.emptyList();
```

Several problems with this attempt:

- its a compiler error as `allWidgets.sort(...)` doesn't return a list; but even if it did...
- this sorts the widgets in time ascending order whereas I believe I want descending
- it doesn't take the differential (`numWidgets - retentionSize`) into consideration

**Can anyone help nudge me across the finish line here?**

Comment: You are mostly looking for [prioriity queue with fixed capacity and custom comparator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878026/is-there-a-priorityqueue-implementation-with-fixed-capacity-and-custom-comparato)

Comment: If the list `allWidgets` is huge, wouldn't it be a better approach to delete the items in question from this list immediately
w/o creating the `oldest` list?

Comment: Sure, but I can't delete a widget unless I already know the list is bigger than `retentionSize` **and** the widget (based on its create time) sorts past the `retentionSize` cutoff.

Comment: Forget it. You can simply run the program more often to keep the `deleteList` from growing too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should sort the stream, rather than the list. The first element should be newest.

Then `skip` the first `retentionSize` widgets. It doesn't matter that you skipped more elements than there are in the stream. `skip` doesn't care. Now, only the oldest (`numWidgets - retentionSize`) widgets remain in the stream.

```
List<Widget> allWidgets = getSomehow();
List<Widget> deleteList = allWidgets.stream()
                          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Widget::getCreateTime).reversed())
                          .skip(retentionSize)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will sort the list every time, even if `retentionSize` is greater than the number of widgets. If this is causing performance problems, you can just add an explicit check for that:

```
List<Widget> deleteList;
if (numWidgets > retentionSize) {
    deleteList = allWidgets.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Widget::getCreateTime).reversed())
                 .skip(retentionSize)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    deleteList = List.of();
}
```

If you instead want everything *but* the elements in `deleteList` (as if you have deleted them), use `limit`:

```
List<Widget> allWidgets = getSomehow();
List<Widget> thingsNotInDeleteList = allWidgets.stream()
                          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Widget::getCreateTime).reversed())
                          .limit(retentionSize)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `skip(long n)` operation:

```
    List<Integer> allWidgets = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    int retentionSize = 2;
    List<Integer> result = allWidgets.stream().skip(retentionSize).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
```

Or you can use `limit(long maxSize)` depending on how you sort your list.

Answer (score 0):

*the* `Widget`*s must be sorted in natural order depending on the* `createTime`
the oldest widgets are the first in row

```
List<Widget> deleteList = (numWidgets > retentionSize)
    ? allWidgets.stream()
        .sorted((w1, w2) -> w1.getCreateTime().compareTo(w2.getCreateTime()))
        .limit(numWidgets - retentionSize).collect(toList())
        : Collections.emptyList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
List<Widget> deleteList = getSomehow().stream()
                                      .sorted(comparing(Widget::getCreateTime))
                                      .skip(retentionSize)
                                      .collect(toList());
```

If you want to delete or do something else immediately with all those oldest widgets, then you can use `forEach` instead of `collect`:

```java
getSomehow().stream()
            .sorted(comparing(Widget::getCreateTime))
            .skip(retentionSize)
            .forEach(w -> /* do something here */);
```